# Ruby DBI fetch can't handle all-zero dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, dbi

I'm trying to access our database with some fairly simple CGI/Ruby and DBI:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require "dbi"
dbh = DBI.connect("dbi:Mysql:my:mydb", "XXXX", "XXXX")

...

query = "select ETA from mydb.mytable where ID = #{someval}"
rows = dbh.execute(query)
while row = rows.fetch() do
    # Do some stuff
    ...
end
```

That works fine most of the time, but I hit a record which broke it with the error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbd/Mysql.rb:120:in `parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbd/Mysql.rb:120:in `parse'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbi/row.rb:66:in `block in convert_types'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbi/row.rb:65:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbi/row.rb:65:in `each_with_index'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbi/row.rb:65:in `convert_types'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbi/row.rb:75:in `set_values'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dbi/handles/statement.rb:226:in `fetch'
        from /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test:39:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test:36:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test:36:in `<main>'
```

After a bit of detective work I found that it had a date of 0000-00-00 which `fetch()` doesn't like. Undefined dates are OK, and DBI in Perl can handle all zero dates, it's just DBI in Ruby.

I can fix the database, and I'll try to get the app which wrote the value to the database fixed too, but I think that my Ruby should be resilient to such things. Is there a way to work around this, maybe using `rescue` somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use `fetch_hash`. This fetches all data as strings, which is a little awkward as you need to convert to dates, integers, etc., but does give you the opportunity of trapping the error on the explicit conversion. This also makes it much easier to identify the bad record(s):

```
query = "select ETA from mydb.mytable where ID = #{someval}"
rows = dbh.execute(query)
while row = rows.fetch_hash() do
    begin
        eta = Date.parse row["ETA"]
        # Do something with the ETA
        ...
    rescue Exception => e
        puts "Error parsing date '#{row["ETA"]}': #{e}<br>\n"
        # Make do without the ETA
        ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
query = "select ETA from mydb.mytable where ID = #{someval}"
rows = dbh.execute(query)
begin
    while row = rows.fetch() do
        # Do some stuff
        ...
    end
rescue Exception => e
    puts "#{e}<br>\n"
    retry
end
```

This works quite nicely as though the retry is starting a new while loop, rows maintains its state so the fetch resumes on the next record.

The only problem is that it's hard to identify the bad record(s). To fix that I issued more queries without the offending field. My somewhat ugly solution:

```
results = Hash.new
hit_error = false

query = "select ETA,UNIQUE_ID from mydb.mytable where ID = #{someval}"
rows = dbh.execute(query)
begin
    while row = rows.fetch() do
        # Do some stuff
        ...
        results[row[1]] = row[0]
    end
rescue Exception => e
    hit_error = true
    retry
end
if hit_error
    query = "select UNIQUE_ID from mydb.mytable where ID = #{someval}"
    rows = dbh.execute(query)
    while row = rows.fetch() do
        id = row[0]
        unless results.has_key?(id)
            begin
                query = "select ETA for mydb.mytable where UNIQUE_ID = #{id} limit 1"
                error = dbh.execute(query)
                error.fetch()    # expect this to hit same error as before
                puts "Unexpected success for UNIQUE_ID #{id}<br>\n"
            rescue Exception => e
                puts "#{e} at UNIQUE_ID #{id}<br>\n"
            end
        end
     end
  end
```

Finally I'm not sure how valid it is to use DBI/Ruby, it seems deprecated. Same for MySQL/Ruby. I also tried Sequel with little success.

Answer (score 0):

Sequel can handle invalid dates if you use the mysql adapter:

```
DB = Sequel.connect('mysql://user:password@host/database')
DB.convert_invalid_date_time = :string # or nil
DB.get(Sequel.cast('0000-00-00', Date))
# => "0000-00-00"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's for Sequel not DBI. I did try using Sequel, but for reasons unknown it couldn't cope with some of my queries - I'm not 100% sure what was causing the problem but I think it might have been a `WHERE` statement which looked like `A and B and (C or D or (E and (F or G)))`

Comment: Note that in Sequel you can use raw SQL fairly easily, you aren't forced into using the DSL to create the queries.Sorry for responding about Sequel, I see now it was only mentioned in another response, not in your original post.

Comment: Yes I was vaguely aware of raw SQL in Sequel. From what I saw of Sequel it looked really nice, I just didn't have the heart to work through the problems as I've not got much time to spend on this stuff. I'll definitely give it a second look at some point.